# Print Contents of Variables to body of email python 3.7

Tags: python, html, smtplib, email-formats

trying to send email through python.  Can get it to send email with correct text content in the body but it's printing the the actual variable name "New Companies" instead of it's content.  here's the code and the resulting email.

(not sure why the html tags aren't showing up in my code below, but I used html and body tags before and after the email content)

Any and all help is appreciated.

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

EMAIL_SERVER = 'blahblah'
EMAIL_PORT = 25

f = open('diff.txt', 'r')
NEW_COMPANIES  = f.read()


EMAIL_FROM = 'blabal'
RECIPIENT_LIST = ['blahblah']

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = EMAIL_FROM
msg['To'] = ", ".join(RECIPIENT_LIST)
msg['Subject'] = 'North Carolina New Business Registration'


body = '''<html>
<body>

New Business Names:<br><br>
body.format('NEW_COMPANIES')
<br><br>
Affiliate: r2thek
<br><br>
Website Link: 
https://www.sosnc.gov/online_services/search/by_title/_Business_Registration
</body>
</html>'''

body.format('NEW_COMPANIES')

msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'html'))


smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP(EMAIL_SERVER, EMAIL_PORT)
smtpserver.sendmail(EMAIL_FROM, RECIPIENT_LIST, msg.as_string())
smtpserver.quit()
```

Email Result:

New Business Names:

{NEW_COMPANIES}

Affiliate: r2thek

Website Link: https://www.sosnc.gov/online_services/search/by_title/_Business_Registration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like you've passed any variables to format the string, you'll need to do

```
body.format(variable1, variable2, etc)
```

In your case I think it's just the one variable, so wherever you stored what NEW_COMPANIES should be needs to be used as the argument for str.format()

Comment: So, i'm wanting to assign a text file to NEW_COMPANIES and then write the contents of that file into the email.  would it go something like this: 
 NEW_COMPANIES  = open(diff.txt, 'r')

Comment: you're going to need to read in the file, opening it isn't enough.  you'll have to do  `f = open('diff.txt', 'r')` then `NEW_COMPANIES = f.read()`

Comment: so i just updated the code with what you suggested and  it's throwing me a NameError: name 'body' is not defined.  Which it looks like it is to me.

Comment: a few things, your body variable should be                                                    ```body = '''<html>
<body>

New Business Names:<br><br>
{}
<br><br>
Affiliate: r2thek
<br><br>
Website Link: 
https://www.sosnc.gov/online_services/search/by_title/_Business_Registration
</body>
</html>'''```
then do:
`msg.attach(MIMEText(body.format(NEW_COMPANIES, 'html'))`

Comment: basically remove `body.format` from the actual body variable and replace it with curly braces `{}`, then format the `body` variable when you call `msg.attach`.  also remove that other call to `body.format` before `msg.attach`